# How to create Bootstrap rows in a React component?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, bootstrap-4

I have a Hit const which displays products (from Algolia). I use it in my main component. I would like to display the products in a row, however, I don't know how to do that, since if I write the row class around the const (in the main component) it doesn't work.

The Hit const is in a way mapping multiple products and I can't create a row from it, because placing row around Hit in the main component treats it as if it were one item and placing row inside of Hit treats each product as one row.

How could each product from Hit be displayed as a column inside a row?

This is the Hit const:

```js
const Hit = ({ hit }) => (
  <div className="col-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
    <a className="mb-5 d-block font-color-black cursor-pointer">
      <div
        className="mb-3"
        style={{
          paddingBottom: "125%",
          background: `url("${hit.image}") center center/cover`,
        }}
      ></div>
      <p className="font-size-subheader mb-2 font-weight-medium">
        {hit.product}
      </p>
      <p className="font-size-subheader font-weight-medium pb-2 borderbottom border-color-black">
        {hit.cena} <span className="hit-em">€</span>{" "}
      </p>
    </a>
  </div>
);
```

This is the return of the main component, where Hit is used:

```js
return (
  <InstantSearch
    searchClient={searchClient}
    indexName="Besedilo"
    searchState={props.searchState}
    createURL={props.createURL}
    onSearchStateChange={props.onSearchStateChange}
  >
    <div className="py-5 my-5">
      <div className="py-4">
        {/* Main Content */}
        <div className="custom-container">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-12 col-lg-10 offset-lg-2">
              <div className="collection">
                <div className="row mb-5 collection-1">
                  <Hits hitComponent={Hit} /> //this is how Hit is used
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </InstantSearch>
);
```

Comment: I think this depends a bit on your Bootstrap version, so maybe reread the [grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) section of your bootstrap version, but generally speaking afaik `col`s always have to sit within a `row` and a `row` must have `col`s to work, whereby there can be just one `col` that takes the whole width.   
I vaguely remember, that a `row` within a `row` needs to be encapsulated by it's own `container` but I'm not sure on that.

Comment: @luroc thanks for your suggestion. I have already read the documentation on the grid system. Otherwise, I am using Bootstrap version 4.4.1.

Comment: When I put your code in a codepen without the react stuff, replacing `custom-container` with `container` it seems to work (or I don't get what's the problem)
https://codepen.io/luroc/pen/qBXdvoL

Comment: @luroc The problem I have is that the Hit const is in a way mapping multiple products and I can't create a row from it, because placing row around Hit in the main component treats it as if it were one item and placing row inside of Hit treats each product as one row.

Comment: So you don't render one hit component for each hit? Have you tried that? Or is that what `Hits` is doing? Then depending on how `Hits` is designed, it might need to be a [fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) (in case you don't know about them), so each individual `Hit` component is a direct child of the `row` div.